# Matching references with Zero amount total

Tags: excel, vba, match

[image]

Dear Friends

I am trying to write a VBA code that could delete the matched Rows the code should matche refereneces in the row(ex A1 match A2 and B1 match B2) with sum amount of C1 & C2 = Zero.

in the above case system should check Row# 1 and match it with Row# 2 by matching A1 with A2 fields and match B1 with B2 also sum amount of C1 and C2 = should be nill.

once matched system should delete the two rows and repeat this proccess again to the end of the sheet.

Thanks

Salem H.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you have tried to write.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
For i = 1 To LastRow
    aValue = ws.Cells(i, 1) 'get values from first row
    bValue = ws.Cells(i, 2)
    cValue = ws.Cells(i, 3)
    If aValue = ws.Cells(i + 1, 1) And bValue = ws.Cells(i + 1, 2) Then 'compare to next row
        If cValue + ws.Cells(i + 1, 3) = O Then 'if adding values from Column C = 0 then
            ws.Cells(i, 3) = 0 'write 0 in both rows
            ws.Cells(i + 1, 3) = 0
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Xabier Thanks it Works